# How to get each element in array and split them into two variables from a delimiter

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get each `element` in an `array`, separate them from its `delimiter`, and store them into two different `variables`. I can only get the last `iteration` of my `foreach loop`. Any answers are fully appreciated.

This is want I wanted to accomplish:

```
$string1 = array('AL8941786046','AL8941786046');
$string2 = array('464646', '555');
```

And here is the array that I wanted to work:

```
Array ( [0] => AL8941786046|464646 [1] => AL8941786046|555 )
```

First iteration will be this first element `AL8941786046|464646`, then I separate this first element into two `string` using `explode` function. using this line of code

`list($string1, $string2) = explode('|', $myArray, 2);`

Now I can only get the last `iteration` only the second element `AL8941786046|555`

Here is my code:

```
             $string1 = array();
             $string2 = array();
             $myArray = array('AL8941786046|464646','AL8941786046|555');
             foreach ($myArray as $val) {
                $ars = $val;
                list($string1 , $string2 = explode('|', $val, 2);
             }
```

Comment: cause you are overwriting `$string1 , $string2` on each iteration. Use array instead

Comment: I did not understand what you mean for "I can only get the last iteration of my foreach loop". What is your goal?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest still not working

Comment: @Tobia question edited, sorry for confusion

Comment: @Dre, stop making mistakes and errors - and it will work. Trust me

Comment: @Dre ok I confirm my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want two arrays as result:

```
         $string1 = [];
         $string2 = [];
         $myArray = array('AL8941786046|464646','AL8941786046|555');
         foreach ($myArray as $val) {
            $arr=explode('|', $val, 2);
            $string1[]=$arr[0];
            $string2[]=$arr[1];
         }
```

This will be the output:

```
$string1: Array ( [0] => AL8941786046 [1] => AL8941786046)
$string2: Array ( [0] => 464646 [1] => 555 )
```

Comment: worked perfectly!  brackets from initialization not working on my PHP, so I changed it to `array()`. anyway big thanks Tobia

Answer (score 0):

```
$string1 =[];
         $string2 =[];
         $myArray =  array('AL8941786046|464646','AL8941786046|555');
         foreach ($myArray as $val) {
            $string1[]=explode(‘|’,$val)[0];
            $string2[]=explode(‘|’,$val)[1];
         }
$array=array_combine($string1,$string2);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the elements in the array to build two arrays that contain the first and the second part of the elements, you can do this:

```
$string1 = [];
$string2 = [];
$myArray = ['AL8941786046|464646', 'AL8941786046|555'];

foreach ($myArray as $val) {
    $exploded = explode('|', $val, 2);

    $string1[] = $exploded[0];
    $string2[] = $exploded[1];
}
```

This will give you:

[image]